# why Extending VARCHAR column size (from less than 255 to greater than 256) use copy not inplace

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

In the mysql 5.7 innodb-online-ddl-operations,he said " In-place ALTER TABLE does not support increasing the size of a VARCHAR column from less than 256 bytes to a size equal to or greater than 256 bytes. In this case, the number of required length bytes changes from 1 to 2, which is only supported by a table copy (ALGORITHM=COPY) ".
but why can't it be like adding a column? Adding a column will also change the storage structure of the row data, but it is achieved through inplace+rebuildtable , and allows dml in executing stage

I know why use copy,but i can't understand why not use inplace+rebuildTable

Comment: To a certain extent, the answer is "because that's the way it is."  A VARCHAR of 255 uses a very different (and more efficient) data structure than a VARCHAR of 256 or more.  It can't make that change inplace. It's just an implementation decision in MySQL.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 uses UTF8MB3 which causes VARCHAR(255) to use not more than 768 bytes (3*255+1=766 bytes max). In this case the value is stored in-page. When you expand the column definition then the number of length bytes increases, total data length may oversize 768-byte limit, and moving the part of data from the data pages to the overflow pages during ALTER TABLE become possible. This process cannot be performed INPLACE, so COPY is selected.

Comment: Err, because more space is required?

Answer (score 0):

There is already data in the current column.  There would be no data in an added column.

With multiple steps:

1. ALTER to add new column (INPLACE)
2. UPDATE the the new copy from the old column -- *This will take longer than the COPY.*
3. ALTER to rename columns and DROP the old column -- possibly not INPLACE.

`pt-online-schema-change` can possibly do the desired ALTER with virtually no downtime.  (This may be your best bet.)

Your question asked "why":

- The 1-byte vs 2-byte length was a small optimization that gets in the way.
- Virtually everything that can be done without a COPY is implemented in 5.7.

The COPY is performed this way:

1. Create a new table with the new schema (bigger varchar)
2. Copy all the data over.  -- This is the slow part.
3. Rebuild the indexes.  (Perhaps this could be optimized away, but that might get tricky to implement.)  This *may* also be slow.
4. Rename tables and drop the old copy.

ptosc is similar (and you *could* do this yourself -- but getting all the subtleties right is tricky):

1. Create a new table with the new schema (bigger varchar)
2. Add some TRIGGERs to keep track of changes during the following steps.
3. Copy all the data over in chunks.  The indexes are probably maintained rather than build-rebuilt.
4. Lock the tables just long enough to copy the last chunk.  This is the only blocked time, and it is short.
5. Rename tables and drop the old copy.

The total time will be longer, but the blockage will be much shorter.